# My notebooks integrated webcam isn't working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: webcam, motion

I installed a software called motion which uses the webcam though I wasn't with enough patience to learn how to use it and uninstalled it with sudo apt purge. But after I did my webcam stopped working.

```
lsusb -v | grep cam
```

Gives:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

I tried running

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

and then

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

But it still not working.

The weird thing is that the camera led is still on. Can I have any spyware and the software messed with it?

I can't use it with cheese neither with google hangouts in chrome. And I also tried restarting the computer.
also

```
dmesg | grep cam
[    1.821760] usb 1-1.5: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[   13.841178] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:670b)
[   13.890386] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input13

dmesg | grep video
[   13.262101] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.841178] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:670b)
[   13.890306] uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   13.890309] uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[   13.890310] uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   13.890312] uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   13.890460] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  212.279744] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_MIN) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  216.240017] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_MIN) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  218.203670] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_MIN) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  220.362531] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  220.362534] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  220.362535] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  220.362537] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  220.362539] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
```

Comment: try installing cheese using `sudo apt install cheese` then open it and see if it detects your webcam

Comment: No device found it says.

Comment: Okay, sorry I can't help you further. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me will see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I had a newer version of the linux kernel installed that didn't had some modules. So I just returned to a previous version through my dual boot menu and it fixed it.